# How to get Default Template(Style Code) of UWP for Controls in Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls using VisualStudio 2019?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I had included the Nuget Package for Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls in my UWP project.
I tried to get the Default Template for any controls inside this package like DataGrid using VS2019. But, Edit Template-->Edit Copy options was Disabled. How to get the default Template and Styles of this Package?[image]

Controls from Microsoft.UI.Xaml like Button,TextBox,etc.. have Edit copy options. Controls from the  toolkit package only not available. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the same with WinUI controls when using WinUI 2.X NuGet package., you can't directly create a default style from the Visual Studio.

> How to get the default Template and Styles of this Package?

You could go to the [Github page of Community Toolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) and check the source code of the Community controls. For example, you could find the style of DataGrid here:[DataGrid.xaml](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml).