# "Edit a copy" option disabled in Visual Studio for custom control

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, winrt-xaml, visual-studio-2022, c++-winrt

I created a custom user control "controls:MyControl" using xaml and winrt/c++. This control is part of a nuget package.

To test for further modification from user side, I added the package to a sample project. Now when I try to copy the template of custom control using "Edit template" and "Edit a copy" in VS 2022, the "Edit a copy" option seems to be disabled.

Please suggest if there needs to be any extra step done for copying the template of a custom control.

Also as a 2nd question, for some of my modified controls I am not able to copy the "Style" but "Template" only. Read through the documentations but couldn't get much help. It would be great if anyone could help with these 2 queries.

Comment: I don't think you could get the style from the NuGet package. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149919/how-to-get-default-templatestyle-code-of-uwp-for-controls-in-microsoft-toolkit